# Updating Rubygems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Very recently I created a gem on RubyGems.org. However I've worked on a new update and can't seem to figure out how to update a RubyGem. I've looked at the user guides, but I can't easily find any articles that specify how to update a RubyGem. Is there an easy way from the command line or from the website? I need to get the new update public soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You just push the gem:

```
$ gem push my_gem-1.0.0.gem
```

Comment: @Beakr: Did you change the version number?

Answer (score 1):

When generating your gem's files and directories it is recommended that you use one of the available tools for creating gems for example [bundler](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle.1.html) or [Jeweller](https://github.com/technicalpickles/jeweler). They have predefined tasks that make it easy to update a gem using a versioning system. Have a look at their respective documentation.

If that is not possible. Keep your files under some form of version control. It will make it easy to add changes and update the current version of your gem.
Have a look at this [tutorial](http://rubysource.com/crafting-rubies-best-practices-while-cutting-gems/) on crafting gems.

Answer (score 1):

First you can change the version number. If it is already exist.Then You can push the latest  .gem(**my_gem-x.x.x.gem**). Please refer Guide:-[Guide](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this excellent [guide](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler)